# OpportunityFieldHistory EditedBy or ModifiedBy attribute

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-history

I have a question on the OpportunityFieldHistory tracking. Per the following, the "Edited By" field is available.

OpportunityFieldHistory Report

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_opp_field_history.htm&type=5

However, the Object Reference here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm

does not indicate the EditedBy field is available. Is there a way to query who actually edited the opportunity, for the field that was tracked?

Thanks!

Venkat Rangan

Answer (score 2):

Edited By is just an alias for the CreatedById field. You can query this to see who the edit was made by.